# Description of a Space of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Here is my question: Denote by $V$ the following space of functions on $\mathbb{R}$:

$f\in V$ if and only if there exists a nonnegative integer $k$, complex numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ and purely imaginary numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\in i\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i e^{\lambda_i x}$. Let equip $V$ with the seminorms

$$\lVert f\rVert_{\infty,k}=sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \lvert f^{(k)}(x)\rvert, \;k\geqslant 0$$

where $f^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of $f$. Now denote by $\overline{V}$ the completion of $V$ wrt to these seminorms. We have a natural inclusion $\overline{V}\subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and moreover $\overline{V}$ is contained in the subspace of smooth functions which have all their derivatives bounded. Obviously, $\overline{V}$ contains all periodic functions and so also finite sums of such functions. On the other hand, I think that $\overline{V}$ contains no compactly supported function apart from $0$. So now my question is this: Does there exist an alternative an more concrete description of the space $\overline{V}$?

I know my question is rather vague but I hope there exists a nice description of this space $\overline{V}$!

Thanks in advance.